# JavaScript Popups not displaying

Tags: javascript

I don't understand what is wrong with the code.  I am doing a training exercise and it still won't work.

Functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function popUp(event, text, color) {
        var popElem = document.getElementById("popUp");
        var x = window.event.clientX + 15;
        var y = window.event.clientY + 15;
        popElem.style.left = x + "px";
        popElem.style.top = y + "px";
        popElem.style.backgroundColor = color;
        popElem.innerHTML = text;
        popElem.style.display = "block";
    }
    function clearPop() {
        var popElem = document.getElementById('PopUp');
        popElem.style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What's the id of the element? Is it "popUp" or "PopUp"? You're using both, but it'll be case specific.

Comment: Can you post your html/where you are calling this as well, please?

Comment: Please define "_won't work_". What you want the code to do, and what it does instead?

Answer (score 0):

99% will be the mistake of your id (`popUp` or `PopUp`)?

here is an example with the same id.

```html
<div id="popUp"></div>

<button onclick="popUp(this, 'im pop text', 'aqua')">
POP
</button>
<button onclick="clearPop()">
CLOSE
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function popUp(event, text, color) {
    var popElem = document.getElementById("popUp");
    var x = window.event.clientX + 15;
    var y = window.event.clientY + 15;
    popElem.style.left = x + "px";
    popElem.style.top = y + "px";
    popElem.style.backgroundColor = color;
    popElem.innerHTML = text;
    popElem.style.display = "block";
  }

  function clearPop() {
    var popElem = document.getElementById('popUp');
    popElem.style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```